# Is it possible to use an underlined letter as keyboard shortcut in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, stylesheet

I want to create a button that can be triggered with a keyboard shortcut based on a letter of the button text; the letter should be underlined, in order to make the shortcut more visible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the [QShortcut](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qshortcut.html) class:

> On certain widgets, using '&' in front of a character will automatically create a mnemonic (a shortcut) for that character, e.g. "E&xit" will create the shortcut Alt+X (use '&&' to display an actual ampersand). The widget might consume and perform an action on a given shortcut. **On X11 the ampersand will not be shown and the character will be underlined. On Windows, shortcuts are normally not displayed until the user presses the Alt key, but this is a setting the user can change. On Mac, shortcuts are disabled by default. Call qt_set_sequence_auto_mnemonic() to enable them. However, because mnemonic shortcuts do not fit in with Aqua's guidelines, Qt will not show the shortcut character underlined.**